# How can I use ftrace filtering to see the call stack above a function?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ftrace

It's well-documented how to use `ftrace` to find the function graph *starting* from a certain function, e.g.

```
# echo nop > current_tracer
# echo 100 > max_graph_depth
# echo ksys_dup3 > set_graph_function
# echo function_graph > current_tracer
# cat trace
# tracer: function_graph
#
# CPU  DURATION                  FUNCTION CALLS
# |     |   |                     |   |   |   |
  7)               |  ksys_dup3() {
  7)   0.533 us    |    expand_files();
  7)               |    do_dup2() {
  7)               |      filp_close() {
  7)   0.405 us    |        dnotify_flush();
  7)   0.459 us    |        locks_remove_posix();
  7)               |        fput() {
  7)               |          fput_many() {
  7)               |            task_work_add() {
  7)   0.533 us    |              kick_process();
  7)   1.558 us    |            }
  7)   2.475 us    |          }
  7)   3.382 us    |        }
  7)   6.122 us    |      }
  7)   7.104 us    |    }
  7) + 10.763 us   |  }
```

But this only returns the function graph starting at `ksys_dup3`. It omits the full function graph that *leads* to `ksys_dup3`:

```
  7)               |  el0_svc_handler() {
  7)               |    el0_svc_common() {
  7)               |      __arm64_sys_dup3() {
  7)               |        ksys_dup3() {
  7)   0.416 us    |          expand_files();
  7)               |          do_dup2() {
  7)               |            filp_close() {
  7)   0.405 us    |              dnotify_flush();
  7)   0.406 us    |              locks_remove_posix();
  7)               |              fput() {
  7)   0.416 us    |                fput_many();
  7)   1.269 us    |              }
  7)   3.819 us    |            }
  7)   4.746 us    |          }
  7)   6.475 us    |        }
  7)   7.381 us    |      }
  7)   8.362 us    |    }
  7)   9.205 us    |  }
```

---

Is there a way to use `ftrace` to filter a full function graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say all of ftrace is well documented ([here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt)). There is no way to do what you want though, because the filtering ability of ftrace is implemented through triggers that can start/stop tracing exactly when an event happens. Setting `set_graph_function` will trigger a trace start when the function is entered and a trace stop when it's exited. Since when you enter `el0_svc_handler` you cannot know beforehand if `ksys_dup3` is going to be called, there is no way to write a trigger to start the trace on such a condition (that would require being able to "predict the future").

You can however do fine grained filtering with the `set_ftrace_pid` parameter writing a program that only does what you need, running a full trace on that program and filtering on the parent `el0_svc_handler`.

---

In case you don't actually know which parent functions are being called before the one you want, you can do a single targeted run with the `func_stack_trace` option enabled to get an idea about what the entire call chain is, and then use that output to set the appropriate filter for a "normal" run.

For example, let's say I want to trace `do_dup2`, but as you say I want to start from one of the parent functions. I'll first write a dummy test program like the following one:

```c
int main(void) {
    printf("My PID is %d, press ENTER to go...\n", getpid());
    getchar();
    dup2(0, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I'll compile and start the above program in one shell:

```
$ ./test
My PID is 1234, press ENTER to go...
```

Then in another *root* shell, configure tracing as follows:

```bash
cd /sys/kernel/tracing
echo function > current_tracer
echo 1 > options/func_stack_trace
echo do_dup2 > set_ftrace_filter
echo PID_OF_THE_PROGRAM_HERE > set_ftrace_pid
```

**Note**: `echo do_dup2 > set_ftrace_filter` is **very important** otherwise you will trace and dump the stack for every single kernel function, which would be a huge performance hit and can make the system unresponsive. For the same reason doing `echo PID_OF_THE_PROGRAM_HERE > set_ftrace_pid` is also important if you don't want to trace every single `dup2` syscall done by the system.

Now I can do one trace:

```bash
echo 1 > tracing_on
# ... press ENTER in the other shell ...
echo 0 > tracing_on
cat trace
```

And the result will be something like this (my machine is x86 so the syscall entry functions have different names):

```
# tracer: function
#
# entries-in-buffer/entries-written: 2/2   #P:20
#
#                                _-----=> irqs-off
#                               / _----=> need-resched
#                              | / _---=> hardirq/softirq
#                              || / _--=> preempt-depth
#                              ||| /     delay
#           TASK-PID     CPU#  ||||   TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
#              | |         |   ||||      |         |
           a.out-6396    [000] ....  1455.370160: do_dup2 <-__x64_sys_dup2
           a.out-6396    [000] ....  1455.370174: <stack trace>
 => 0xffffffffc322006a
 => do_dup2
 => __x64_sys_dup2
 => do_syscall_64
 => entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe
```

I can now see the entire call chain that led to `do_dup2` (printed in reverse order above) and then do another normal trace from one of the parent functions (remember to disable `options/func_stack_trace` first).

Comment: Yeah after reading through the documentation and endless Google searches I wasn't optimistic this was directly possible, but I was hoping maybe there was a way - thanks for confirming my pessimism  - and thanks for the alternative tips, they're useful!

Comment: Regarding "(that would require being able to "predict the future")." - I understand what you're getting at, but it wouldn't be too difficult to support this use case specifically in the function_graph tracer - log all function graphs without filtering (this has a performance penalty of course), and when completing a graph, check if it contains a filter function before committing it to the trace. Not sure if ftrace's current implementation allows for running logic before committing an event to the trace.

Comment: @DanielKleinstein *"Not sure if ftrace's current implementation allows for running logic before committing an event to the trace"* - yeah, I am pretty sure it does not unfortunately. Doing what you say would require saving a trace in a tree format and performing DFS on the tree. Theoretically doable, but expensive and probably a very niche use case.

Comment: Not sure how niche of a use case it would be - I think ftrace is very commonly used for understanding new kernel systems, easily seeing full function graphs leading to a specific function seems valuable. You're right that there'd be a performance penalty, but it would be opt-in - and I would guess that the DFS in most cases would be mostly shallow (just for the record I'm not sure that BFS wouldn't work equally-as-well). Anyways, food for thought 